# Primes in $\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right]$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Is it true that any prime $p\in\mathbb{Z} $ with the property that $\left( \frac{p}{d}\right)=-1$,where $d=4k+1,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is also prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right]$($d$ is such that the ring is Euclidean) ?

Comment: When $d=4k+1>0$, $(1+i\sqrt d)/2$ is not in the ring of integers in ${\bf Q}(i\sqrt d)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I have corrected it now

Comment: But there's still $i$ in the title, and in the factorization of $\alpha^2+d$.

Comment: My calculations were wrong, they depended on the form of p. So, I think this should tell us whether it remains prime or not in the ring of integers

Comment: There are only finitely many Euclidean quadratic fields, right?